# How to create a virtual FIDO U2F passkey for Chromium?

Tags: security, chrome, authentication

I have read in [German news](https://www.br.de/nachrichten/netzwelt/passkeys-warum-wir-bald-keine-passwoerter-mehr-brauchen) that soon passkeys will replace the username/password login method. I think this won't happen soon but I think the idea is great and it will come. Passkeys are little USB devices but they also have RFID. You can [see one here on Amazon](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B07M8YBWQZ).
Please note, that these are not like old common [RSA USB tokens](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/SecurID).

The new standard is called FIDO U2F and it's made by the [FIDO alliance](https://fidoalliance.org/). Google, Microsoft, Qualcomm, Mastercard and many others are part of it. I think it's gonna be a big thing.

My question is:
How to create a virtual passkey under linux which can be used in the Chromium browser? So I can login to sites supporting passkeys. Without having a physical passkey.

Answer (score 0):

Passkeys (as implemented by Google/Apple) have some additional features on top of the standard FIDO2/WebAuthn HSKs (hardware security keys like Yubikey/Solokey) such as multi-device access, cross device authentication, and cloud synchronization. They're available on supported platforms without emulation: https://passkeys.dev/device-support/

For example, when using a PC with Chrome and an Android device with Chrome, the Chrome browser on the PC can issue a passkey registration/authentication request to the Android device over Bluetooth.

This works very well on Linux. For reference I'm running Chrome v116 (from Google's repo) on LMDE 5 (based on Debian 11).

If you're intent on creating a virtual HSK, it may be emulated with QEMU: https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/system/devices/usb-u2f.html